# where to find resource if I want to better/further understand gazebo::common::events

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to learn more about Event::connect disconnect

but there is no tutorial on official website

API Documentation about "event" is very short,and I can't understand
http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/2.2.1/classgazebo_1_1event_1_1Events.html#ab0fefed82c8ab22f67cf5a3870bcb9ef

where to find resource if I want to better/further understand gazebo::common::events ??

Because I encountered a problem as following:

I have two plugin,

one world plugin "evaluation_platform", another one is model plugin "arm_control"

in _onUpdate() of the world plugin "evaluation_platform",
I use DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin(update_connection) to Disconnect "_onUpdate()" under some condition

I tested these two plugin independently, and they worked well as I want,

but, when I used them together ,things went wrong

_onUpdate() of the world plugin "evaluation_platform" cannot be disconnected

and I guess the critical point is in model plugin "arm_control"

So .I want to learn more about Event::connect & disconnect to find out the problem

Thank you!!

這裡有沒有說中文的夥伴啊～～？

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7367/where-to-find-resource-if-i-want-to-better/further-understand-gazebo::common::events/) by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2014-10-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-11-04**:
Can you show some of your code so we can try to reproduce the problem?

**Comment by [YuanGao](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/991/yuangao/) on 2014-11-06**:
有啊，真是太难找到同伴了，有时间一起讨论下？你是做什么项目的啊？

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2014-11-20**:
機器手臂 與電腦視覺整合

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[Here](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/4.0.0/group__gazebo__event.html) is the API documentation for the event system.

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/a929e28fed25615d7eb60be9a78e627fea11dbec/gazebo/common/Events.hh?at=default) is a set of example event definitions.

Basic usage:

1. Define an event (see `gazebo/common/Events.hh` for examples).
2. Create a Connection, which registers a callback to an Event. Make sure to keep the Connection alive (don't destroy it), until you are done.
3. Trigger the event, and the callback will be run.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1